# Difference between the spinal cord and vertebrae column

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

What is the difference between the spinal cord and the vertebrae column, they both run through from the head to the abdomen. Does any one have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertebral column is a bony, segmented structure that supports the torso/head and thorax. The spinal cord is a bundle of nerves that runs inside the structure of the vertebral column. So - they run together, but are completely separate.